# Spring security is always redirecting on login page

Tags: spring-security, spring-3

I have this configuration :

```xml
<bean id="customizedFilterSecurityInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="accesDecisionManager"/>
    <property name="securityMetadataSource">
        <security:filter-security-metadata-source use-expressions="true" >
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="permitAll" />
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/js/**" access="permitAll" />
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/externe*.do" access="permitAll" />
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/*.do" access="isAuthenticated() or isRememberMe()" />
        </security:filter-security-metadata-source>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
   class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginFormUrl">
            <value>/login.jsp</value>
    </property>
    <property name="forceHttps">
            <value>false</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="externeServiceInterceptor"  class="fr.global.commun.springSecurity.MySecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    ...
    <property name="securityMetadataSource">
    <security:filter-security-metadata-source use-expressions="true" >
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/externe*.do" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        </security:filter-security-metadata-source>
    </property>
```

The problem is that all the requests that begin with `/externe` are redirected on the login page, and if I delete the `/*.do`, I don't acces to the Interceptor, but directly on the struts action Externe*.

Comment: Are you sure request matches `/externe*.do`? Can you run spring security in DEBUG mode (add `log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG` to log4j.properties) and show output after requesting `externe*.do`?

Comment: Well, it was an idiot error ... I forgot to add : 
security:filter-chain pattern="/externe*.do" filters="externeServiceInterceptor" />

Comment: In problems like this with Spring Security always DEBUG first ;)

Comment: Should I delete this question ?

Comment: You should post answer with solution yourself and mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This entry in the xml file was forgotter :

```
<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <security:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/externe*.do" filters="externeServiceInterceptor" />
    </security:filter-chain-map>   
</bean>
```

Comment: This is most likely a very bad idea. You are routing these requests through this filter without any other filters in the chain (as far as I can tell), which means that, even if you can authenticate somehow, you are likely to leak thread-local security contexts, thus potentially having users access the system as other users.